# Select random partitioned record with specified number of record in every partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a table (named QuestionBank) on which every question are stored :

```
Id     Topic     Hardness    Position
4        1          3           4
5        1          2           1
6        1          1           2
7        1          3           3
8        1          3           4
9        2          2           1
10       2          2           2
11       2          3           3
12       3          1           1
13       3          1           1
14       3          1           2
```

Every question belongs to a Topic and has it's own Hardness and Position (every similar question based on their content have same position on corresponding Topic).

Note that the value in Position column is meaningless and it just partitions similar questions in a topic.

The goal is selecting N records with X records of Harness=1 and Y records of Hardness=2 and Z records of Hardness=3 and so on in a random manner; with this constraint that as much as possible there are no records with similar topic and position returned in result set.

For example, the records with Id=4 and Id=8 are similar in either Topic and Position hence one of them are desired to be in result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

1. First if any `Topic, Position` have multiple questions assign each of these a random ordering `RN1`.
2. Then sort by that but randomly within each group. All the `1` values for `RN1` will obviously be ordered first before getting onto `2` that denotes the second question for a particular  `Topic, Position` combo.
3. Then use the result of that in a `ROW_NUMBER` calculation partitioned by `Hardness` to make the final `SELECT` easier.

.

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Topic, Position 
                                       ORDER BY Newid()) AS RN1
         FROM   QuestionBank),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY RN1, Newid()) AS RN2
         FROM   T1),
     T3
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Hardness 
                                       ORDER BY RN2) AS RN3
         FROM   T2)
SELECT Id,
       Topic,
       Hardness,
       Position
FROM   T3
WHERE  ( Hardness = 1
         AND RN3 <= 3 )
        OR ( Hardness = 2
             AND RN3 <= 2 )
        OR ( Hardness = 3
             AND RN3 <= 2 )
ORDER  BY Topic,
          Position,
          Hardness
```

If you are only selecting a small proportion of the table each time there will likely be much more efficient ways however.

Comment: thanks a lot @Martin for your solution.
I work on it since yesterday and it works perfect.

Comment: Now i stuck in another problem:
if i going to limit number of records related to a topic instead of hardness of them . what would be the solution ?

For example 3 records of Topic=1, 4 records of Topic=2 and 2 records of Topic=3 (instead of for example 2 records of Hardness=1,... )

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

You can a `WHILE` cycle to select a question at a time.

To select the random question:

1. select all records of Hardness 1 to a temporary table
2. Use [rand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) to select one of them
3. Test if there was previously a questin selected with the same Topic/Position, if so don't had to the selected questions and remove it from the select made in point 1.
4. Do the steps 2 to 3 until you have the N records for Hardness specified
5. Do the steps 1 to 4 for the other Hardness values.